# How to run code once all DependencyProperties have finished binding?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I have two DependencyProperties on a custom UserControl. They're based on each other, so if only one property is provided then the other will be calculated. The problem is that I do not want this calculation to run if both values are provided, as it can be a hit on performance.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyAProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(PropertyA), typeof(Guid?), typeof(UserControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnPropertyAChanged));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyBProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(PropertyB), typeof(MyClass), typeof(UserControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnPropertyBChanged));

private static void OnPropertyAChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = (MyUserControl)d;
    if (control.PropertyB == null)
        control.CalculatePropertyB();
}
private static void OnPropertyB Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = (MyUserControl)d;
    if (control.PropertyA == null)
        control.CalculatePropertyA();
}
```

In this sequence of events where I use my UserControl and bind both properties, the following sequence occurs :

1. PropertyA is set
2. PropertyB is calculated
3. PropertyB is set

Is there something I can use that will only execute after BOTH properties have finished updating their bindings?

The only way I have found to actually do this is in OnChanged method, run something on the dispatcher at the [DispatcherPriority](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) of `ApplicationIdle`, which really isn't ideal in my case. I'd like to ensure it calculates before `DispatcherPriority.Input`

```
private static void OnPropertyAChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = (MyUserControl)d;
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        if (control.PropertyB == null)
            control.CalculatePropertyB();
    }), DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
}
```

Comment: How about a Loaded event handler?

Comment: Users will be cycling through records, so it needs to happen whenever the values change too.

Comment: What is the exact use case? When the user cycles to the next record, either one or the other or both properties are set? By data binding?

Comment: Yes, this control is part of a screen of controls displaying the current record. When the user selects a different record in a grid, it will swap out the DataContext to the new record

Comment: That may work. I'm currently experimenting with rewriting this code to have different logic, but I was hoping there was some event I was missing that would fire after all the bindings had finished. I was surprised that the `Dispatcher` code didn't work unless I had it set all the way down to `DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle`

Comment: There is DataContextChanged. Perhaps start a shortly delayed action there.

Comment: I did test a bit with the `DataContextChanged` event, however it doesn't seem to get updated every time the record changes. I believe the code behind the form is simply bound to the Grid's SelectedItem, so the DataContext isn't necessarily being set to a new value. I could potentially try `SourceUpdated`, but I'm OK with having to rewrite what I'm doing to use different logic if there's nothing easy available. I'm half-way through it now anyways.

Comment: Are you able to write some sort of "PropertyChanged" Queue? 
What I am thinking is something where you have a queue with a count threshold (lets say 2). Within each "OnProperty_X_Changed" you would add properties to this queue. Then once the threshold is triggered you would call an `Action` or `Func` to carry out some code. This way you dont have to track what order things are done in, you just need a count of "things" and then carry out the code you want following this.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously that UI thread will update properties from view one by one

But there is possibility to use async handlers with small delay for allow to release UI thread and switch it to update other dependencyProperties.
In continuation of async method - all properties will be updated and you will be able to analize their values.

```
private bool _isUnderReCalculation = false;

public async Task Update()
{
   await Task.Delay(100); // this is advantage of async\await - we can release UI thread for complete update values.

   // continuation of method need to call only one time.
   // bindings completed
   if (_isUnderReCalculation ) return;

   try
   {
      _isUnderReCalculation = true;

      // TODO: run some method.
   }
   finally
   {
      _isUnderReCalculation = false; 
   }
}
```

And in propertyChanged handler you need to call this method

```
private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = (MyUserControl)d;
    control.Update();
}
```